# c++ 11. Matrices multiplication

Tags: c++11, matrix, multiplication

Hello. I write matrix class but i have some problem with matrices multiplication which have different dimensions.

```
template< typename T, size_t Row, size_t Col >
class Matrix
{
public:
.....................................
template< typename MulT >
auto operator * (const MulT& other) -> Matrix<T, Row, other.getColNum()>
{
    if (other.getRowNum() != getColNum())
        throw std::logic_error("Multiplication are not possible");

    Matrix<T, Row, other.getColNum()> temp;

    // Some operations.

    return temp; // Must return matrix with this type Matrix<T, Row, other.getColNum()>
                    // but it dont work.
}
.....................................
}; // class Matrix
```

This code don't work. It is possible to resolve this problem?

Comment: So what doesn't work?  Does it not compile?  does it compile but overheat your computer?  does it compile and then make all the lights in the town dim?  All you have done is say "This crap don't work" and pasted your code.  Show some effort for God's sake and describe your issue like a human being.  Jesus.

Comment: @moo-juice Even though what you're saying is comprehensible, please mind your diction.

Comment: @embert - Apologies - the freemium lack of effort these days gets to me sometimes.  Happy sunday! :)

Answer (score 1):

`other.getColNum()` is probably not a `constexpr` function and can therefore not be used as a template non-type argument.

Read up on `constexpr` here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to check the if `if (other.getRowNum() != getColNum())` at runtime, this should be done at compile time.  One way to do this is to define the operator only for when the multiplication is valid. In  this case:

```
template< typename T, size_t Row, size_t Col >
class Matrix
{
public:
.....................................
template<size_t _RHSWIDTH>
Matrix<_T, _RHSWIDTH, Row> operator * (const Matrix<T, _RHSWIDTH, Col> &rhs) const
{
    Matrix<_T, _RHSWIDTH, Row> temp;

    // Some operations.

    return temp;
}
.....................................
}; // class Matrix
```

As a result, any attempt to multiply matrices which cannot be multiplied will fail at compile time.  For a complete example, I wrote a complete matrix template a long time ago which uses very similar syntax: https://github.com/Enseed/GenericGeometry/blob/master/Matrix.h